# Connecting ggplot2::geom_point() with ggplot2::geom_line() in repeated measures

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to connect the dots in my plot based on `id`. The problem is that on my x-axis I am positioning the `geom_point()` with `position_dodge()`, so I am not quite sure how I should map this.

**Reprex:**

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- structure(list(id = c("id24", "id24", "id27", "id27", "id29", 
                            "id29", "id34", "id34", "id35", "id35", "id44", "id44", "id01", 
                            "id01", "id03", "id03", "id04", "id04"), phase = c("time1", "time2", 
                                                                               "time1", "time2", "time1", "time2", "time1", "time2", "time1", 
                                                                               "time2", "time1", "time2", "time1", "time2", "time1", "time2", 
                                                                               "time1", "time2"), value = c(3.72638957446809, 3.92324338297872, 
                                                                                                            3.7271745106383, 3.79455578723404, 3.96383646808511, 4.28965153829787, 
                                                                                                            4.44174112765957, 4.80494985106383, 4.11124778723404, 4.39377629787234, 
                                                                                                            2.91550910638298, 3.21677434042553, 3.4524314893617, 4.2533229787234, 
                                                                                                            3.07149085106383, 3.38445914893617, 3.8882985106383, 4.78346468085106
                                                                               ), group = c("group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", 
                                                                                            "group1", "group2", "group2", "group2", "group2", "group2", "group2", 
                                                                                            "group3", "group3", "group3", "group3", "group3", "group3")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                        -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(df, aes(group, value)) +
  geom_point(aes(group = phase),  position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

I know that this would have been the most straighforward way of doing this:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(phase, value)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = id)) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

But I need to have `group` in the x-axis, which is then positioned by `phase`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for is essentially a nested categorical x axis. This is what faceting is for in ggplot, but isn't quite the look you are aiming for. However, you can set various theme elements to hide the fact that you are faceting. I think this is easier than the alternative, which is pivoting your data on `phase` and drawing `geom_segment`s for each `id`, but this also requires a bit of spoofing of the categorical x axis, and gives essentially identical results:

```
ggplot(df, aes(phase, value)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = id)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = c(1.5)), colour = "gray85") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = c(0.5)), colour = "gray85") +
  geom_line(aes(group = id, color = id)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0.5, 2.5), ylim = c(2.49, 5), expand = 0) +
  theme_light() +
  labs(x = "group") +
  facet_wrap(.~group, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "npc"),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = NA),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Without faceting:

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "phase") %>% 
  mutate(group = as.factor(group)) %>%
  mutate(x0 = as.numeric(group) - 0.25, xend = as.numeric(group) + 0.25) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = group, colour = id)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x0, y = time1)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = xend, y = time2)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x0, y = time1, xend = xend, yend = time2)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = levels(as.factor(df$group))) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Allan. Yeah, I am aware of this workaround, but I was really looking for a way to do it without the facet. If not possible, I will accept your answer

Comment: @FMM it is possible to do it without faceting, but it would require a bit of reshaping of your data and a bit of hacking. A "facet that doesn't look like a facet" might be best (see my update). Remember, what you are asking for here is essentially a nested categorical x axis. This is what faceting is for in ggplot. The alternative is to pivot your data on phase and draw `geom_segment`s, which might be more what you are after. I can certainly show you an example if you don't like the updated version of the facets.

Comment: Your updated answer looks great! I am curious about this other approach you mentioned.. I guess I never tried this.. would you mind to show an example?

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!